# How to retrieve a list of spaces for a Google Chat user (not the bot)

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-oauth, google-chat, google-chat-api

I am trying to derive a list of spaces that an authenticated user belongs to in Google Chat. I suspect the scope .../auth/chat.spaces.readonly is the right permission to achieve this. At the moment, I cant find any examples on how to retrieve the spaces for a user.

The only examples I have found has to do with retrieving the list of spaces for a bot with chat.spaces.list().

Answer (score 1):

To use this you need to use service account authentication, read documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list)
and here is an [example](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs) to follow for service account authentication

Comment: Came here from "first answers" review queue. This answer is link-only, but it covers a pretty complex topic so I think linking to official documentation and official source code can be permissible.

Comment: Can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486527/how-to-create-and-send-a-threaded-message-in-google-chat-with-ruby ?